# Subset of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group. Let $$H = \{b \in G.\ bab^{−1} \in \langle a \rangle \}.a \in G$$

Prove that if G is a finite group, then H is a subgroup of G.
I think that a good approach is to prove that $$ba^i b^{-1} = (bab^{−1})^i \text{ for i an integer}$$
But I need a pointer on how to do that

Comment: Try writing it out. $(bab^{-1})(bab^{-1}) = bab^{-1}bab^{-1} = ba^2b^{-1}$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$H $ is not empty as $e_G \in H$

Let $b_1,b_2\in H$ then $b_1ab_1^{-1},b_2ab_2^{-1}\in \langle a \rangle $. So let $b_1ab_1^{-1}=a^m$, $b_2ab_2^{-1}=a^p$

Now $b_1b_2a(b_1b_2)^{-1}=b_1(b_2ab_2^{-1})b_1^{-1}=b_1a^m b_1^{-1}=(b_1ab_2^{-1})^m=a^{pm}\in \langle a\rangle$. Thus $b_1b_2\in H$.

Again $a=b^{-1}a^mb$. Since $G$ is a finite group and $b^{-1}ab \in G $ so $o(b^{-1}ab)=k$ (say).

So $(b^{-1}ab)^m=a\implies (b^{-1}ab)^{km+1}=a^{km+1}\implies 
b^{-1}ab=a^{km+1}\in \langle a\rangle $

[Since $o(b^{-1}ab)=k\implies(b^{-1}ab)^{km+1}=b^{-1}ab$]

Comment: Some typos (I think): in line 3, $b_1ab_1^{-1}$, $b_2ab_2^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$, not $\in H$;  in second-to-last line: $(b^{-1}ab)^{km+1}=a^{k+1}$, not $=a^{km+1}$; in last line: missing close parenthesis.

Comment: you got it right @WillOrrick

Comment: but what can we say about b^(-1)ab if G is infinite?

Comment: Nothing about its order @tmac_balla

Answer (score 1):

The condition $bab^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle$ is equivalent to $b\langle a\rangle b^{-1}\subseteq \langle a\rangle$, and when $G$ is finite, this condition is equivalent to $b\langle a\rangle b^{-1}= \langle a\rangle$ (since both sets are finite). Now what can you say about collection of such $b$'s? Is it what you want?

Comment: but why is it equivalent? It is true only for one fixed a in G

Comment: How elements of $<a>$ are? they are powers of $a$. If $bab^{-1}$ is in $<a>$ then $ba^2b^{-1}=(bab^{-1})^2$ is also in $<a>$, and so the set $b<a>b^{-1}$ is inside $<a>$.

Comment: Groups is absolutely right, what you, tmac_balla, are asking basically is to prove that the *normalizer* of $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup. Which it is.